# how to sort array of objects by arbitrary list in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was looking for a way to sort array of object by an arbitrary list. Lets assume I have this array of objects.

```
[
  {
   "_id": "4JEEuhNIae",
   "category": "grocery"
  },
  {
   "_id": "4JW7miNITl",
   "category": "food"
  },
  {
   "_id": "4Je4kmrrbZ",
   "category": "coffee"
  },
  {
   "_id": "4JgAh3N86x",
   "category": "coffee"
  }
]
```

This is the array that I would like to use as sorting criteria. Records with `food`should come first, then `coffee`and `grocery`.

```
['food','coffee','grocery']
```

Result should be:

```
[
  {
   "_id": "4JW7miNITl",
   "category": "food"
  },
  {
   "_id": "4Je4kmrrbZ",
   "category": "coffee"
  },
  {
   "_id": "4JgAh3N86x",
   "category": "coffee"
  },
  {
   "_id": "4JEEuhNIae",
   "category": "grocery"
  },
]
```

How can I do this type of sorting on mongodb by using mongoose? I really don't want to make any operations on the code after fetching data.

Comment: Your code is a list field inside a document ? Or it is a list of documents ?

Comment: @SergiuZaharie it is a list of documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running a custom comparator function with the native JavaScript **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** method on the array returned from the **[`cursor.toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray)** method:

```
var order = ["food", "coffee", "grocery"];
var docs = db.collection.find().toArray().sort(function(a, b) { 
    return order.indexOf(a.category) - order.indexOf(b.category);
});
printjson(docs);
```

**Sample Output**

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "4JW7miNITl",
        "category" : "food"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "4Je4kmrrbZ",
        "category" : "coffee"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "4JgAh3N86x",
        "category" : "coffee"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "4JEEuhNIae",
        "category" : "grocery"
    }
]
```

---

With the new MongoDB 3.4 version, you should be able to leverage the use of the native MongoDB operators **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** and **[`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/#exp._S_indexOfArray)** in the aggregation framework.

- The **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline step allows you to **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** new fields to existing documents without knowing all the other existing fields.
- The **[`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/#exp._S_indexOfArray)** expression returns position of particular element in a given array.

So putting that altogether you could try the following aggregate operation (with MongoDB 3.4):

```
var order = ["food", "coffee", "grocery"],
    projection = { 
        "$addFields" : { 
            "__order" : { "$indexOfArray" : [ order, "$category" ] } 
        } 
    },
    sort = { "$sort" : { "__order" : 1 } };
db.collection.aggregate([ projection, sort]);
```

Comment: It seems i can't directly write custom sort function for mongoose, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/798 I need to use ```db.eval``` well thank you