# how to get mongoDB documents in priority order

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Is there any way to get documents from mongoDB in priority order.

the documents in mongo are indexed like this :

```
{
 "productId":1
},
{
 "productId":2
},
{
 "productId":4
},
{
 "productId":5
},
{
 "productId":6
},
{
 "productId":7
}
```

i need to get documents in order as term query order

i try this query but not work :

```
{
    "productId": {
        "$in": [
            {
                "$numberLong": "5"
            },
            {
                "$numberLong": "7"
            },
            {
                "$numberLong": "1"
            },
            {
                "$numberLong": "4"
            },
            {
                "$numberLong": "6"
            },
            {
                "$numberLong": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i expect result are documents sorted as term queries order :

```
{
 "productId":5
},
{
 "productId":7
},
{
 "productId":1
},
{
 "productId":4
},
{
 "productId":6
},
{
 "productId":2
}
```

Comment: could you post your code to process and th request and explain waht you want to achieve

Comment: i need to get result in the priority order that means i need to get some documents before other

Comment: Can you sort it with "_id": -1

Comment: post the code , and which priority ? by Id , date or waht ? you question is quit too broad

Comment: i need to get result in the order as ids order in query 

for example in ids query : [1,9,7,10,5]

i need to get document have id 1 first and 9 second etc ..

Comment: BY sorting with Id with do the thing

Comment: i don't need to sort by asc or desc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort array of objects by arbitrary list in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356781/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-by-arbitrary-list-in-mongo)

Comment: @Caconde thanks yes that i try to find and it's work as query but i need the way to convert this query to spring data mongo ,, do u have some way ??